# "Xe kombiniert mit Ye [eröffnet/ eröffnen] Ihnen" Singular oder Plural Verb Kongruenz

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich habe diesen Satz gelesen und fand es klingt falsch, dass **"eröffnet"** im Singular steht:

> Ihre Produktentwicklung kombiniert mit unseren individuell auf Ihre
> Anforderungen zugeschnittenen Lösungen eröffnet Ihnen völlig
> neue Märkte!

Die Pluralform (eröffnen) klingt zunächst korrekt, da es ja A und B, sprich zwei Subjekte gibt. Je öfter ich die beiden Varianten aber lese desto unsicherer werde ich mir. Gibt es dazu eine Regel? Macht "kombiniert" automatisch eine Singularform hieraus? Oder *eröffnet die Kombination*, ergo Singular?

Comment: Rein formal ist nur *Produktentwicklung* das Subjekt. Das spricht für Singular.

Comment: Es sollte heißen _... mit unseren ..._ .

Comment: Oder: "unserer Lösung"

Comment: @MartinPeters stimmt, im original steht dort nicht "lösungen", habe ich übersehen.

Comment: @Alex Kein Problem; kann passieren.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Der Satz hat nur ein Subjekt, und zwar das im Nominativ Singular stehende Substantiv *Produktentwicklung*. Der Teil

> kombiniert mit <s>unserer</s> *unseren*<sup>*</sup> individuell auf Ihre Anforderungen zugeschnittenen Lösungen
>
> <sub><sup>*</sup> *unseren:* Dativ Plural von *unser*</sub>

ist kein eigenständiges Subjekt, sondern eine Apposition, die das Subjekt näher beschreibt. Als solche müsste sie mit Kommas vom Hauptsatz abgesetzt werden:

> Ihre Produktentwicklung, kombiniert mit *unseren* individuell auf Ihre Anforderungen zugeschnittenen Lösungen, eröffnet Ihnen völlig neue Märkte!

Comment: Oder "unserer zugeschnittenen Lösung" - eine ähnlich geringe Korrektur, die ebenfalls zu einem validen Satz führt.

Comment: *Als solche müsste sie* klingt ein bisschen unsicher, vielleicht solltest du lieber mit einem "sogar" die nächste doch eigentlich fällige Korrektur einleiten.

Answer (score 1):

Man könnte erstmal einen Teil des Satzes ersetzen durch "X":

> X eröffnet Ihnen völlig neue Märkte!

Jetzt muss man natürlich schauen, ob "X" im Plural oder Singular steht, was ziemlich einfach ist, um zu entscheiden, ob es "eröffnen" oder "eröffnet" sein muss. Ich denke, die Verwirrung kommt wegen dem aktuellen "X" an sich:

> Ihre Produktentwicklung kombiniert mit unserer individuell auf Ihre Anforderungen zugeschnittenen Lösungen [...]

Hier kombiniere ich die Produktentwicklung mit Lösungen und heraus kommt eine mit Lösungen kombinierte Produktentwicklung, also Singular. Im Plural würde man ja sagen, dass sowohl die Produktentwicklung als auch die Lösungen neue Märkte eröffnen, bloß möchte man ja von *der Kombination* (Singular) sprechen.